# Trying to populate a drop-down menu form element with items from a relationship list

Tags: python, html, flask, jinja2, flask-sqlalchemy

I am working on a simple web app for an online school.

So far, the administrator can create a teacher profile and create and assign a class (lesson) that teacher is responsible for:

```
class Teacher(db.Model):
    teacher_username = db.Column(db.String(50), primary_key=True, nullable=False)
    password = db.Column(db.String(50), nullable=False)
    # define a one-to-many relationship to track assigned classes
    assigned_classes = db.relationship('Class', backref='teacher', lazy=True)
```

And assign a class (lesson) to this profile when creating a new class:

```
class Class(db.Model):
    class_id = db.Column(db.String(50), primary_key=True, nullable=False)
    teacher_username = db.Column(db.String(50), db.ForeignKey('teacher.teacher_username'), nullable=False)
    subject = db.Column(db.String(20), nullable=False)
```

Flask views for these two work perfectly.

Now I want to create a view that will delete a selected relationship from a Teacher object.

The HTML should display two drop-down menu form elements and a 'delete' button.

The first drop-down should list all the teacher usernames (works fine) and the second one should show the selected teacher's assigned classes - relationships. I am trying to loop through teacher.assigned_classes list in order to populate this form element but it's always blank. I am a bit of stuck here as far as Flask view goes.

The HTML form should probably look something like this:

```
<form method="POST">
        <label for="teacher_username">Select Teacher:</label>
        <select name="teacher_username">
            <option value="">Select Teacher</option>
            {% for teacher in teachers %}
                <option value="{{ teacher.teacher_username }}" {% if teacher.teacher_username == selected_teacher %}selected{% endif %}>{{ teacher.teacher_username }}</option>
            {% endfor %}
        </select>
        <br>

        <label for="class_id">Select Class:</label>
        <select name="class_id">
            <option value="">Select Class</option>
            {% if selected_teacher %}
                {% for class in teacher.assigned_classes %}
                    <option value="{{ class.class_id }}">{{ class.class_id }}</option>
                {% endfor %}
            {% endif %}
        </select>
        <br>

        <button type="submit">Delete Class</button>
    </form>
```

I don't know if I'm missing something and I'm not even sure if it's possible to populate this class_id dropdown in real time - so admin can switch teachers and see the update right away.

Any thoughts?

I tried a few views - I tried to extract assigned_classes as a list, then removing selected items from the list, even clearing entire list - nothing worked. The problem is, I can't get the form to display assigned classes at all, so I'm sort of in the dark.

The only think I do know works is the very process of assigning lessons, since I can print teacher.assigned_classes as a list and it shows everything that's supposed to be there.

Comment: So `print(teacher.assigned_classes` in your flask backend code prints the classes to the terminal but your html code does not render them? Because from my understanding you would have to call `teacher.assigned_classes.all()` in order to actually retrieve the class Objects since you use `dynamic=lazy` in your relationship definition

Comment: On a side note: Using `Class` as class-name is not recommended as it clashes with a Python keyword. Common alternatives are `Klass` or `Cls`.

Comment: Building on the comment above, you might want to have a look at https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/orm/queryguide/relationships.html